# Redux change 'state' used in other reducers when using combined reducers

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm using redux and redux-saga.  I have several reducers such as:

`userReducer`, `itemReducer`, etc.  Each one serves a specific purpose for encapsulated related data.

The situation I have is that for every API request being made a token is returned.  This token needs to update in the state for`userReducer`.

Here's an example:

```
// Action
export function getItems () {
  return {
    type: 'GET_ITEMS'
  }
}


//Saga
const getItems = function * getItems (action) {
   const response = yield call(api.getItems)
   yield put({ type: 'GET_ITEMS_SUCCESS' })
}


//itemReducer
switch(action.type) {
  ...
  case 'GET_ITEMS_SUCCESS':
    return {
        ...state,
        action.data
    }
  ...
}
```

This is just a basic example, now in this scenario, I'm getting items and updating the state when successful, pretty straight forward.  What I also want to do is update the `userReducer` state with a token that would be available in `action.token`.

The obvious way is there would be duplicate cases, which really isn't reasonable.

The second option is in my `userReducer`, I can do a check before the switch for if the action contains a token and if it does, update it's state (seems ok, I guess).

The last option I can think, is to somehow modify my saga so that I can issue a new action 'UPDATE_TOKEN' or something similar, when each saga is run.

Would anyone have any suggestions on best practice on how to handle this?

EDIT:

Ok, so the best way I can see to do this now is by adding another yield in saga, such as:

`yield put({ type: 'UPDATE_TOKEN', token: response.token })` and just use `UPDATE_TOKEN` in my userReducer.  This seems pretty straight forward, just need to add it wherever I want to actually perform this action.

Comment: The token is returned in the API call, or you're just wrapping token and data fetching in the `api.getItems` function?

Comment: Token is returned in the API call

Comment: Then I guess your solution in the edited question is what you'll want to do. But it's still kinda weird that you get a new token for every request. Usually you'd like to make a token fetch request and then a resource fetch request with a token - in this approach you'd have a lot more solutions to consider using sagas.

Comment: For what it's worth, a simple middleware would also work, you could catch every action that contains a token in the payload and dispatch UPDATE_TOKEN. This way the reducers could focus on their own piece of state only.

Comment: @timotgl I actually was testing that, but wasn't able to figure out how to dispatch and call next(), it would either only dispatch the token update or next, calling both causes max call stack.

Comment: @sarneeh that is an option too, this is a jwt token, so basically for each request was going to extend the expiry automatically

Comment: @dzm Put a breakpoint in the middleware with your browser's devtools and follow the flow of execution. Calling dispatch and afterwards next() should work fine. To confirm that your middleware is integrated correctly, you can dispatch a dummy 'MIDDLEWARE_WAS_CALLED' action every time before you invoke `next()`.